# mongoose aggregation reverse lookup or lookup without localField

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation, mongoose-populate

I want to run aggregation on Plan Schema and fetch a Feedback that has reference Id `planId`.
But If I want to populate with lookup I need the reference ID in Plan but I don't like this strategy of saving reference Id, I like everything seperated.

Is there any way to populate without having reference Id.

something like this. but It doesn't work.

```
const pipe = [
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'Feedbacks',
    pipeline: [
      { 
        $match: { 
          planId: '$_id'
        }
      }
    ],
    as: 'feedback'
  }
}]
await Plan.aggregate(pipe);
```

```
export interface Plan {
  _id: ObjectId;
  ...

}
export interface Feedback {
  planId: ObjectId;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. for anyone else:

```
{
  from: 'Feedbacks',
  let: { planIdInPlan:"$_id"},
  pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr:
                  {
                    $eq:['$planId', '$$planIdInPlan'] 
                  }
                }
                }
            ],
  as: 'feedback'
}
```

Comment: just one question, is not it a very bad with slow speed and worse performance? or it will be better to lookup from the right way (run the aggregate on feedback collection and lookup the plan collection), and then add more pipelines?

Comment: @KasirBarati I don't know man, I gave up on mongoose and its typings. realized NoSQL isn't my thing so changed to Postgresql completely.